# Jquery sending key/value paired array to PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

To be honest Im not sure how to frame this question, but here goes.

I have a form with the following input fields:

```
<input name="key[23]" type="text" />
<input name="key[29]" type="text" />
<input name="key[65]" type="text" />
```

I can create an array with Jquery to send to the PHP script like so:

```
    var new_keys = new Array();
$('input[name="keys[]"]').each(function() {
    new_keys.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

However I dont know how to create the array when the input fields already have a key: **input name="test[45]"**

I tried changing my method to using a class selector instead of the input name, but I cant get the keyname.

What I need to do is send the keyname and its value to PHP so I can update a table where the keyname equals the table ID number. This is simple to do if I wasnt using Ajax.

Hope that makes sense.

Edited

```
<form method="post" id="add-form" class="form" onsubmit="return false;">
<input class="required" type="text" name="name" id="name" />
<input class="required" type="text" name="keys[32]" />
<input class="required" type="text" name="keys[65]" />
<textarea name="Test"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $.fn.submitForm = function() {
        var name = $('#name').attr('value');
        var new_keys = new Array();
        $('input[name="keys[]"]').each(function() {
            new_keys.push($(this).attr('value'));
        });

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            data: { 'new_keywords' : new_keywords, 'name' : name },
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'article/scripts/article.scripts.php',
            success: function($data) {
                var result = $data.result;
                var msg = $data.msg;

                if (result == "success") {
                    formMessageDisplay(msg, result);
                }
                else {
                    formMessageDisplay(msg, result);
                }
            },
            error: function($data) {
                formMessageDisplay('<?php echo AJAX_ERROR; ?>', result);
            }
        })
    }
});
```

This is a cutdown version of the script that I have.

Comment: Just to add, the keynames are dynamic and not static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this which should grab the names of the fields and then assign the values in the array.  You can then process and clean it up in PHP as needed:

```
var new_keys = new Array();
$('input[name="keys[]"]').each(function() {
    new_keys[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
});
$.post('url/to/script/here.php', new_keys, function(data) {
    // process data here on success
}, 'json'); // expecting a json object
```

For further reading on ajax look @ this for using the post method http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: Thanks for that. However if I add an alert before 'new_keys', nothing happens. $('input[name="keys[]"]') doesnt seem to match the selector as the input name has a keyname. If I changed that line to $('input[name="keys[29]"]') then it will match the input field with the name keys[29] and that line will be submitted. Does that make sense?

Comment: From your script I changed mine to: `var old_keywords = new Array(); $('.old-keys').each(function() { old_keywords[$(this).attr('id')] = $(this).attr('value'); });` Which is now working fine

Answer (score 0):

You can try passing the values as an array and the names as another array, then combine them in PHP with [`array_combine()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), like so:

```
var new_keys = new Array();
var new_names = new Array();
$('input[name="keys[]"]').each(function() {
    new_keys.push($(this).attr('value'));
    new_names.push($(this).attr('name'));
});

//Then in PHP
$complete_array = array_combine($new_names, $new_keys);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify you have a form, that you want to send the values off to a php script via javascript/ajax?

If that's the case then you'll have something like:

HTML:

```
<form id="myForm" action="phpScript.location" method="post">
   <input/>...
   <input/>...
</form>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'phpScript/location',
            data: $('form').serialize(),  // This will give you the needed key/pair parameterization you need. 
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'html', // This can be one of many values.  Just defines the expected response type. 
            success: function(data, status, xhr) {
                // Success response
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Serialize documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Comment: I tried to serialize the fields like so: var old_keywords = $('.old-keys').serialize(); This serializes the query string for input fields with the correct class, but it doesnt include the name with keyname. var keys = $('input[name="keys[]"]').serialize(); doesnt work as the keyname is absent.

Comment: What's your expected parameters within the php script?  Is it a key/pair such as: "key[##] => value"?  Or are you looking for a parameter called 'key' with a range of values, ie: key => 1,2,4,5...?