# Passing key-value pairs of multiple related form fields as a JSON string

Tags: jquery

How can I pass the key-value pairs of these related dropdown lists as a JSON string using JQuery? (For instance like: {"32":"3","4":"1"} )

```
<select name="32" rel="select_items">
...
...
</select>

<select name="4" rel="select_items">
...
...
</select>
```

I'm aware of the possibilty to use JQuery's serializeArray(), but I'm not sure how to use this function on the related form items only, rather than the whole form.

Thanks for your support.

Comment: This question has pretty much been answered here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11617257/jquery-sending-key-value-paired-array-to-php?rq=1

Comment: you say "For instance like: {"32":"3","4":"1"}". Is that the required format, or just one possibility? What would you consider as acceptable formats? Does it matter? And how are you sending the data? Via ajax presumably? If you send it in a normal postback it will get url-encoded, and not really any point in using JSON.

Comment: @ADyson True, I'm suggesting any format will do. However, I would like it as a JSON string to store it unaltered in a database (Form sent using AJAX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question correctly: that you want ALL your options serialized into JSON I would do it like this

**HTML**

```
<select name="32" rel="select_items">
  <option value=one>1</option>
  <option value=two>2</option>
</select>

<select name="4" rel="select_items">
  <option value=three>3</option>
  <option value=four>4</option>
</select>
```

**jQuery**

```
var output = {};
$("select option").each(function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     output[value] = $(this).html();
});
document.write(JSON.stringify(output));
```

If you want just the selected ones you can do that with:

```
var output = {};
$("select option:selected").each(function(){
      var value = $(this).val();
      output[value] = $(this).html();
});
```

or you could, like you described yourself, just use serializeArray();

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hsrLLLLs/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = Array();

$('select option:selected').each(function(){
     arr[$(this).parent().attr('name')] = $(this).val();
});
```

It will return an array: ["32":"3","4":"1"]

Answer (score -1):

You can do this to output {"32":"3","4":"1"}

```
$x = $_POST['32'];
$y = $_POST['4'];
$z = array_merge($x, $y);
$output = json_encode($z);
```

This assumes there are other form fields in the form POST and you only want those two.

Comment: the question is asking about posting data _to_ the PHP script in JSON format, not _from_ it